# Countdown and lifepoints, as3

Tags: flash, actionscript, equation

How do I get accurate counting? My game has is a pass or fail scenario based on time.
I need an equation that will work in ActionScript.

'Commence escape within 30 sec or lose 600 life points'
...you see only readout of `lifepoints`, but time needs to be accurate

**I'm not attached to this, it's just an example**

```
var CURRENTCOUNT:int = 0;
var EQUA:int;
//WHERE I WANT TO PUT LINEAR EQUATION
EQUA = 34;//<==EQUATION GOES HERE???
var SPEED:int; 
SPEED = EQUA;
var COUNTDOWN:Number = 600;
var COUNTUP:Number = 0;
//TIMER
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(SPEED,600);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,someFunction);
myTimer.start();
//INCREMENTING++
function someFunction(event:TimerEvent) {
//COUNTDOWN stops count going down, COUNTUP stops count going up
CURRENTCOUNT = COUNTDOWN - myTimer.currentCount + COUNTUP;
//Testing with only a text string to rule out cashing issues 
tx.text = String (Math.abs (CURRENTCOUNT));
}
```

**I've tried this**

```
SPEED=DISTANCE/TIME
```

In place of `currentCount`, but it's not any more accurate. It adds acceleration

```
//VoVf
V++;
COUNT = V*V/X;
```

30 seconds and 600-0 lifepoints and counting I wanted to explain, because it's not a clock. It's pass or fail. They look at there life drifting away.

Description of lifecount. Scene with Death holding a steampunk style timer or gauge and laughing:

- Player has so many seconds to escape '30 seconds
- Lifecount displays loss of players total life '600
- Player can choose between more power or more life if they make it out alive

Comment: Just a side note, but you mean "lose 600 points", not "loose" :-)

Comment: I see your edits.  Still makes no sense.  Why are you using physics equations?  And statements like `If player makes it out of the room, he or she has the same life points` make no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links can explain. They go over delta time and explain ideas useful for accurate counting and scoring. I hope this gets you started.
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/02/19/flash-simple-timercountdown/
http://www.allquests.com/question/2589182/how-to-pause-game.html
http://www.kongregate.com/forums/4/topics/1773
http://www.kirupa.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-286177.html